# Can't format my usb flash from bootable to normal

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, flash

A few weeks ago I decided to format my PC as it wasn't working very well.

Since I didn't have any Windows 7 on disk I decided to use my USB flash drive to do that.

So I made it bootable and formated my PC. Then I tried to reformat the flash back to normal, but I didn't succeed.

[image]

Above you can see my USB flash drive. And in it I have this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the clean command in Diskpart.

1. Open a Command Prompt with admin privileges.
2. Type `diskpart` and press enter
3. Type `list disk` and press enter
4. Find your USB drives disk number in the first column. You'll use the `select disk` command to select your USB drive. If it were disk 3 for example you would type `select disk 3` and press enter. Make sure you choose the proper number for your USB drive as the clean command will completely wipe the selected disk.
5. Type `clean` and press enter.

Now format the USB drive.

Comment: Thank you so much,you literally saved 8gb of data.